# Problems setting div back to display:none after setting it to block

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn about manipulating the DOM using JavaScript, I've learnt some of the absolute basics at codecademy but nothing relating to DOM. This is my first try, the comments I made in my code might look a bit amateur but they're in my own words to help me understand what's going on.

**The issue:**

I am trying to make a button show/hide another div by it's id. I was able to get it to go from `display:none` to `display:block` but then I wanted to be able to click the button again and it hide the menu, so I tried adding in an if/else statement but after several almost random attempts I am stuck.

I have Googled for solutions but none of the code I found looks like mine, I was hoping someone could point out what needs to be done in my code, so I can follow along start to finish.

`if (menu === style.display = 'none')` was just wishful thinking after I tried a few things that didn't work.

I understand it could be done in jQuery, but for me that's not relevant right now as I need to be able to grasp some basic JavaScript to progress.

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5uj0jbep/2/)

My JS

```
//Make Button show/hide div when clicked
function hideShow() {
  //Specify the id I want to add the event to, here it is menubutton and I have added click and told it to look for the function menutoggle
  document.getElementById('menubutton').addEventListener("click", menutoggle, false)
    //Now for the function called menutoggle which will set the id menu to 'block' if it is currently 'none' and to 'none' if it is currently 'block'
  function menutoggle() {
    if (menu === style.display = 'none') {
      document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'none';
    };
  }
};
window.onload = hideShow;
```

Comment: This `if (menu === style.display = 'none')` does not appear to be a valid expression.  What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Element.style.display` reads inline styles..Use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to read css properties(Stylesheet or Inline CSS)

> `==`/(`===` => strict) is comparison operator and `=` is assignment operator. Use comparison operators to test the value and `=` to set the `value/property`

`menu` is undefined in your example, variable `menu` should hold `HTMLElement` having `id` as `menu`

```js
function hideShow() {
  var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
  document.getElementById('menubutton').addEventListener("click", menutoggle, false)

  function menutoggle() {
    if (getComputedStyle(menu).getPropertyValue("display") == 'none') {
      menu.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      menu.style.display = 'none';
    };
  }
};
window.onload = hideShow;
```

```css
.menubutton {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
menu {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="menubutton" class="menubutton">Show Menu</button>
<menu id="menu">
  I am the menu!
</menu>
```

Comment: See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: @RayonDabre Great, this changed and cleaned my code slightly but I was still able to understand it, it also functions a lot better than mine original would have if I had correctly written the if statement. Mine would need 2 clicks to show the menu

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an "=" sign in your if:

```
function hideShow() {
  //Specify the id I want to add the event to, here it is menubutton and I have added click and told it to look for the function menutoggle
  document.getElementById('menubutton').addEventListener("click", menutoggle, false)
    //Now for the function called menutoggle which will set the id menu to 'block' if it is currently 'none' and to 'none' if it is currently 'block'
  function menutoggle() {
    if (menu === style.display = 'none') {
      document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'none';
    };
  }
};
window.onload = hideShow;
```

It should be

```
if(document.getElementById('menu').style.display == 'none')
```

Also, try not to add an eventListener on load. Just do it in your html:

```
<button id="menubutton" class="menubutton" onclick="hideShow()">Show Menu</button>
<menu id="menu">
  I am the menu!
</menu>

function hideShow() {
    if (document.getElementById('menu').style.display == 'none') {
      document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'none';
    };
}
```

Comment: Actually using event listeners is the preferred approach to code inline in attributes in html - keep your code separate from your views.

Comment: This is what I was tyring to achcived with my code, thanks. I can see my mistake now. Although regarding the eventListener I read that is bad practice to add onclick="" into your HTML and you should keep the js out of your HTML

Comment: Actually actually using a framework (like jQuery) is the preferred approach, let it take care of all the crappy stuff while you concentrate on functionality. :)

Comment: @J.V.A. Internally that's still using event listeners.

Comment: Yes, but you don't care about how it's implemented.

Comment: Sure, it is the preferred way. But I find that some people get carried away with the window.onload and then get slow loading pages, then complain about it.

Comment: If you have slow loading pages due to your `onload`, you're doing something wrong.  @GoldenGonaz Stick with what you're doing - don't fall into using code in attributes where everything needs to be global and all the other horrible things that come with it.